# I want to restrict a function based on dimension

Tags: r

I want to make a function that reports an error if the dimension of the y variable is greater than one. This is the code that I've made:

```
my.ecdf<- function(x,y) {
  if(dim(y)<-NULL)
    stop("y has more than one dimension")
  n<-length(x)
  i<-1:n 
  p<-if(x[i]<y) 1 else {
    0
  }
  p/n
}
```

I want to use the function with a single integer as input for y, but I get the error that y has a length of 0. I do not understand. Also, if there are any other errors in my code feel free to point them out, I am new to this program.

Comment: use the statement `if(length(y)>1) stop("blahblah")`

Comment: Your current code is *assigning* dimension, using the left-assignment `<-` operator. Perhaps you want `if (is.null(dim(y)))`?

Comment: I ended up doing if(!is.null(dim(y))) thanks :)

Comment: If you check for a null dimension attribute, be wary that e.g. `matrix(1)` (a 1x1 matrix) won't work, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment operators in R:

```
x <- NULL
NULL -> x
x <<- NULL
NULL ->> x
x = NULL
```

testing for equality:

```
x == NULL
```